# Using org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager in the cloud

Tags: spring, cloud, cloud-foundry, spring-cache

I noticed that Spring reference application (Sagan) uses the **`SimpleCacheManager`** implementation. See [here](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/blob/master/sagan-site/src/main/java/sagan/SiteConfig.java#L112) for source code of Sagan.

I was surprised by this choice because I thought that all but small applications running on a single node would use something like a Redis cache manager and not the simple cache manager.

How can a large application like Sagan -which I assume runs on cloudfoundry- use this simple implementation?

Any comment welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the SimpleCacheManager choice has been made because it was the simplest solution that could possibly work. Note that Sagan is, at least for now, not storing a lot of data in that cache and merely using it to respect various APIs rate-limiting and get better performance on some parts of the application.

Yes, Sagan is running on CloudFoundry (see [this presentation](https://speakerdeck.com/bclozel/spring-dot-io)) and is using CF marketplace services.

Even if cache consistency between instances is not a constraint for now, we could definitely add another marketplace service, here a Redis Cloud instance, and use this as a central cache repository.

Now that we're considering using that cache for more features, it even makes sense to at least consider that use case, since it could lower our monthly bill (pay a small fee for a redis service and use less memory for our CF instances).

In any case, thanks a lot balteo for this insightful question, we've created [a Github issue for that](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/issues/381).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was just asking because I am developping a spring app and I frequently peek into sagan's source code for inspiration. Based on what you said, I might just like you and choose the simplest solution that works!! Thanks again Brian.

Comment: Sagan is a reference app, so that's also why it's made for!
It is evolving though, so I would not be surprised if your question would trigger some changes there. Thanks!

Comment: We use a mixture of in own JVM and external caches. In own JVM is fastest and great for meta data. We have our own data centers and 25-30 MB per node is in internal caches.